# Pagination issue in GitLab

Tags: api, pagination, gitlab

```
gitBranchesFromApi=$(curl -s --user ${gitCredentials} --header PRIVATE-TOKEN:${gitToken} https://addpage.gitlab.com/gitlab/api/v4/projects/$projectId/repository/branches?pagination=keyset&per_page=100)
```

I have added to show 100 git branches but it is showing only 20.
The rest are getting deleted.
Is this correct?

Comment: 20 is the default page limit size... so hard to say. It's possible your `per_page` argument is invalid or maybe you just have 20 branches as a coincidence. Take a look at the response headers to find out.

Comment: I have 87 branches, and I increased the limit to 100. But still not getting all branches.

Answer (score 0):

[Keyset based pagination](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/#keyset-based-pagination) is not supported for [Branches API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/branches.html).

Its only supported for [Projects API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html), [Groups API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/groups.html) and  [Group Audit Events](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/audit_events.html#group-audit-events).

> Keyset-based pagination is supported only for selected resources and ordering
> options: Projects | Groups | Group audit events

Comment: Then should I use offset?
Also, why are some branches being displayed then?
@Jackob Liskow

Answer (score 0):

After removing keyset and adding **page=1**, it's working.